# E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "androidx"

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, sqlite, programación-móvil

estoy realizando una app de tareas con SQLite para aprender acerca de Kotlin y Android Studio. El problema que tengo es a la hora de añadir las tareas a la base de datos, ya que recibo este error:

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "androidx": syntax error in "INSERT INTO tareas (titulo, descripcion, fecha) VALUES androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{aec1dc9 VFED..CL. .F...... 184,550-896,693 #7f0801b8 app:id/descripcion_aña
> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.listadetareas, PID: 25201
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "androidx": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO tareas (titulo, descripcion, fecha) VALUES androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{aec1dc9 VFED..CL. .F...... 184,550-896,693 #7f0801b8 app:id/descripcion_añadir_tarea aid=1073741825}, androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{aec1dc9 VFED..CL. .F...... 184,550-896,693 #7f0801b8 app:id/descripcion_añadir_tarea aid=1073741825}, 30/5/2021
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1919)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1841)
> at com.example.listadetareas.FeedReaderDbHelper.añadirTarea(DB.kt:45)
> at com.example.listadetareas.AnadirUsuarios.onCreate$lambda-0(AnadirUsuarios.kt:32)
> at com.example.listadetareas.AnadirUsuarios.lambda$fysUFCr2_t7Ey5OcDMCqD4gKBRk(Unknown Source:0)
> at com.example.listadetareas.-$$Lambda$AnadirUsuarios$fysUFCr2_t7Ey5OcDMCqD4gKBRk.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
> at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Este es el archivo Anadirusuarios.kt

```
    class AnadirUsuarios : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.anadir_usuarios);
        val recuperar_year = intent.getIntExtra("year", 2021).toString()
        val recuperar_month = intent.getIntExtra("month", 1).toString()
        val recuperar_day= intent.getIntExtra("day", 1).toString()
        val fecha = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.fecha_tarea);
        val btn_añadir_tarea = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_añadir_tarea)
        val date = "$recuperar_day/$recuperar_month/$recuperar_year";
        fecha.text = date;
        btn_añadir_tarea.setOnClickListener {
            val titulo_añadir_tarea = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.titulo_añadir_tarea).toString()
            val descripcion_añadir_tarea = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.descripcion_añadir_tarea).toString()

            if (titulo_añadir_tarea != null && descripcion_añadir_tarea != null){


                var dbHelper = FeedReaderDbHelper(applicationContext);
                dbHelper.añadirTarea(descripcion_añadir_tarea, descripcion_añadir_tarea, date)
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "La tarea $descripcion_añadir_tarea ha sido añadida correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

El archivo de las consultas de base de datos(DB.kt):

```
    class FeedReaderDbHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {

    private val SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + DB_settings.TABLE_NAME +
                "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_TITULO} VARCHAR," +
                "${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_DESCRIPCION} VARCHAR)" +
                "${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_FECHA} VARCHAR)"

    private val SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${DB_settings.TABLE_NAME}"

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES)
    }
    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES)
        onCreate(db)
    }
    override fun onDowngrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion)
    }
    companion object {
        // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
        const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db"
    }
    object DB_settings{
            const val TABLE_NAME = "tareas"
            const val COLUMN_NAME_TITULO = "titulo"
            const val COLUMN_NAME_DESCRIPCION = "descripcion"
            const val COLUMN_NAME_FECHA = "fecha"
        }
    fun añadirTarea(titulo: String, description: String, fecha: String ){
        val db = writableDatabase
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO ${DB_settings.TABLE_NAME} (${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_TITULO}, ${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_DESCRIPCION}, ${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_FECHA}) VALUES ${titulo}, ${description}, ${fecha}")
        db.close();


    }
}
```

Si necesitan algún tipo de información extra no duden en pedirmela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en estas líneas

```
val titulo_añadir_tarea = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.titulo_añadir_tarea).toString()
val descripcion_añadir_tarea = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.descripcion_añadir_tarea).toString()
```

Lo que estás guardando en esas variables no es el texto ingresado en el editText sino el `EditText` en sí mismo. El texto ingresado se ecuentra en la propiedad `text` del editText. Todo lo que debes hacer es guardar en las variables el valor de esa propiedad

```
val titulo_añadir_tarea = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.titulo_añadir_tarea).text.toString()
val descripcion_añadir_tarea = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.descripcion_añadir_tarea).text.toString()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, gracias a ti he solucionado el error. El problema es que ahora recibo este otro, el cual es muy parecido y no logro encontrar el fallo. El log seria este:

Comment: Te lo dejo por aquí por si quieres echarle un vistazo. Gracias: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/465672/e-sqlitelog-1-near