# E/SQLiteLog: (1) near ""

Tags: android, sql, android-studio, sqlite

Estoy realizando una app de tareas con SQLite para aprender acerca de Kotlin y Android Studio. El problema que tengo es a la hora de añadir las tareas a la base de datos, ya que recibo este error (prueba123 es el valor que guarda la variable "descripcion_añadir_tarea"):

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "prueba123": syntax error in "INSERT INTO tareas (titulo, descripcion, fecha) VALUES prueba123, prueba123, 30/5/2021"
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.listadetareas, PID: 28752
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "prueba123": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO tareas (titulo, descripcion, fecha) VALUES prueba123, prueba123, 30/5/2021
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1919)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1841)
        at com.example.listadetareas.FeedReaderDbHelper.añadirTarea(DB.kt:45)
        at com.example.listadetareas.AnadirUsuarios.onCreate$lambda-0(AnadirUsuarios.kt:32)
        at com.example.listadetareas.AnadirUsuarios.lambda$fysUFCr2_t7Ey5OcDMCqD4gKBRk(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.listadetareas.-$$Lambda$AnadirUsuarios$fysUFCr2_t7Ey5OcDMCqD4gKBRk.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Anadirusuarios.kt

```
   class AnadirUsuarios : AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.anadir_usuarios);
    val recuperar_year = intent.getIntExtra("year", 2021).toString()
    val recuperar_month = intent.getIntExtra("month", 1).toString()
    val recuperar_day= intent.getIntExtra("day", 1).toString()
    val fecha = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.fecha_tarea);
    val btn_añadir_tarea = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_añadir_tarea)
    val date = "$recuperar_day/$recuperar_month/$recuperar_year";
    fecha.text = date;
    btn_añadir_tarea.setOnClickListener {
        val titulo_añadir_tarea = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.titulo_añadir_tarea).text.toString()
        val descripcion_añadir_tarea = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.descripcion_añadir_tarea).text.toString()

        if (titulo_añadir_tarea != null && descripcion_añadir_tarea != null){


            var dbHelper = FeedReaderDbHelper(applicationContext);
            dbHelper.añadirTarea(descripcion_añadir_tarea, descripcion_añadir_tarea, date)
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "La tarea $descripcion_añadir_tarea ha sido añadida correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    }
}
```

El archivo de las consultas de base de datos(DB.kt):

```
    class FeedReaderDbHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {

private val SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
    "CREATE TABLE " + DB_settings.TABLE_NAME +
            "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_TITULO} VARCHAR," +
            "${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_DESCRIPCION} VARCHAR)" +
            "${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_FECHA} VARCHAR)"

private val SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${DB_settings.TABLE_NAME}"

override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES)
}
override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
    // to simply to discard the data and start over
    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES)
    onCreate(db)
}
override fun onDowngrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion)
}
companion object {
    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
    const val DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db"
}
object DB_settings{
        const val TABLE_NAME = "tareas"
        const val COLUMN_NAME_TITULO = "titulo"
        const val COLUMN_NAME_DESCRIPCION = "descripcion"
        const val COLUMN_NAME_FECHA = "fecha"
    }
fun añadirTarea(titulo: String, description: String, fecha: String ){
    val db = writableDatabase
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO ${DB_settings.TABLE_NAME} (${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_TITULO}, ${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_DESCRIPCION}, ${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_FECHA}) VALUES ${titulo}, ${description}, ${fecha}")
    db.close();


}
```

Si necesitan algún tipo de información extra no duden en pedirmela. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Necesitas comillas simples para cada valor y encerrar todo values en ()
.. VALUES ('prueba123', 'prueba123', '30/5/2021')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta linea te faltan los paréntesis despues de VALUES

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO ${DB_settings.TABLE_NAME} (${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_TITULO}, ${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_DESCRIPCION}, ${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_FECHA}) VALUES ${titulo}, ${description}, ${fecha}")
```

Debe ser así:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO ${DB_settings.TABLE_NAME} (${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_TITULO}, ${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_DESCRIPCION}, ${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_FECHA}) VALUES ('${titulo}', '${description}', '${fecha}')")
```

También revisa si envía como cadena los campos, sino también te marcara error porque necesitaran ir entre comillas simple.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Comentas que te marca error porque no encuentra un campo fecha, es porque no se crea correctamente tu tabla, te falta una coma (,) y no cerrar el paréntesis ) después de agregar el campo `COLUMN_NAME_DESCRIPCION`

Como lo tienes

```
private val SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
    "CREATE TABLE " + DB_settings.TABLE_NAME +
     "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
     "${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_TITULO} VARCHAR," +
     "${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_DESCRIPCION} VARCHAR)" +
     "${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_FECHA} VARCHAR)"
```

Como debe ser

```
private val SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
    "CREATE TABLE " + DB_settings.TABLE_NAME +
     "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
     "${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_TITULO} VARCHAR," +
     "${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_DESCRIPCION} VARCHAR," +
     "${DB_settings.COLUMN_NAME_FECHA} VARCHAR)"
```

Recuerda que debes actualizar la versión de la base para que cree ne nuevo la tabla correctamente

Comment: Muchas gracías, tenias razón, pero ahora recibo el error: table tareas has no column named fecha in "INSERT INTO tareas (titulo, descripcion, fecha) VALUES ('wqewqeq','wqewqeq', '30/6/2021')". No entiendo por qué, ya que tengo una columna llamada fecha en la linea const val COLUMN_NAME_FECHA = "fecha", no?

Comment: @Angel ya actualice la respuesta respondiendo a tu error, si te sirvió puede marcarla como respuesta aceptada

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!